Dynamic Dispatch, Kotlin
I have this code
open class Shape {
    open fun number(m: Shape) = "1"
    open fun number(m: Rectangle) = "2"
}

class Rectangle : Shape() {
    override fun number(m: Shape) = "3"
    override fun number(m: Rectangle) = "4"
}

fun main() {
    val shape: Shape = Rectangle()
    println(shape.number(shape))
}

I expected 4 to be printed, while it is 3: how does dynamic dispatch work? the invoked function is Rectangle#number(Shape) even tho the object is the same, shape.

The declared types of the arguments are part of the name of the method.  It's called a "signature".

@MattTimmermans my question is about the difference in interpretation of shape as Shape in overloads choice, and as Rectangle in overrides choice

Your two overrides of number have different signatures.  It's exactly as if they had different names.  You are calling number_Shape with a rectangle parameter, so there is no reason to think that number_Rectangle would be called instead.

Functions number(m: Shape) and number(m: Rectangle) are overloads, we dispatch between them not dynamically, but statically. Functions defined in Rectangle are overrides over functions in Shape and they are dispatched dynamically.
That means when the compiler processes the shape.number(shape) line, it sees the shape is of the Shape type, so it chooses the number(m: Shape) function and puts a call to it into the bytecode. The runtime type of the parameter doesn't matter. Then at the runtime it sees the receiver is actually Rectangle, so it executes the Rectangle.number(m: Shape) function.
I think it is the same in most programming languages.
Please see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding


Didn't know overloads are dispatched statically, while overrides dinamically. Is there any tech constraint for this difference, or some else reason?

@Andrea I don't know if this is the reason, but please note the runtime dispatch has to be as quick as possible while the compile-time dispatch doesn't have to be. Dispatching on the receiver only is relatively simple. For overloads we have to take multiple parameters into account and I don't see a way to make it quick. Also, dynamic dispatch is traditionally implemented by a vtable provided by the receiver object, so we don't exactly examine types - we just use the vtable. If we dispatch on param types, that would really require examining all types and making runtime decisions.

What you were expecting is a concept called multiple dispatch. With multiple dispatch, the actual function that gets called depends on more than one of its arguments. Multiple dispatch is supported by some languages, such as C# and Julia. Some languages (such as Python and JavaScript) can do multiple dispatch through the use of an external library.
Kotlin only supports single dispatch, whereby the function called depends on its receiver. This is in common with many languages, such as Java and C++. Multiple dispatch can be simulated in such languages through the use of reflection to check the actual run-time type of its arguments (see example in the linked Wikipedia page).

Then the same example in C#, given the support to multiple dispatch, would print the number 4?

Not exactly the same, but it would if you cast the argument to dynamic type.
